# SSIS package deployment. Changing protection level takes a very long time

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We are in the process of migrating our servers to a new data center. Currently we are on SQL Server 2014 and SSIS packages deploy in seconds.

The new data center has several SQL server 2016 installs and I noticed that on some of them the "Changing protection level" takes a very long time (around 7 minutes!) but on some it is fast. When I change the SSIS project's TargetServerVersion to 2016 the changing protection level is slow on all new servers.

The ProtectionLevel of the project and packages is set to (and has been) to DontSaveSensitive.

What is causing the slowness and how can I troubleshoot this? It eventually does deploy without any errors.

Comment: It is already set to "DontSaveSensitive" in Visual Studio. The process is slow even when I deploy to sql server with no packages present in the catalog.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I solved my own problem. I do not know exactly what cause it, but here is what i did.

It turns out that only one of the projects that we have had the problem I described. That project happened to have multiple packages included. For testing I removed all packages from the project and added one at the time, built the project after each step and tested the deployment. They all worked fine individually and ultimately I ended up with a project with all packages that deploys fast.

This got me thinking that maybe the project file/build files got hosed somehow and they all needed a full refresh/rebuild.